# using html link to middle of a php page with additional parameters

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I'm currently generating a long page using PHP. The page also requires parameters:
`http://host/showFile.php?file=abc`
The resulting page can be quite lengthy and I would like to extend this to position the page at a specific line. I know how to do this using  and adding #tag to the URL for an HTML file, but I can't see how to combine the effect in this case. Putting
`http://host/showFile.php#tag?file=abc`
doesn't work, as PHP doesn't see the file= argument, putting
`http://host/showFile.php?file=abc#tag`
also doesn't work as it assumes the file is then abc#tag.

I could put:
`http://host/showfile.php?file=abc&line=tag`
and change my code to start at the required line, but this would only show the page from the required point onward, and I need to have the whole file viewable by scrolling back.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Bill

Comment: The `#` being latter should be correct. `$_GET['file']` has the `#tag` in it?

Comment: you should anyway echo the whole file and add a javascript logic that will move a given element to viewport

Comment: @diegod The `#` should be read as a separate fragment unless it is URL encoded.

Comment: ok. But we are splitting the hair. the point is how to use the extra informations about which line to show and based on how I read the question it seems like the file gets echoed as the chunk starting from a given line while maybe the solution was just showing it complete and moving the cursor with client side logic

Comment: Well, I assumed that was the case, on checking,  the argument  doesn't have the #tag in it, but the #tag just seems to be ignored. As the page is largely a table, I've put the tags in the <tr id='tag'>, Is this not valid?

Comment: Diegod: I'm not well up on Javascript, Any hint as to how to achieve that?

Comment: @BillPurvis A `#` is not sent to the server. Only the client uses it... so is the question the file not downloading correctly or the positioning being off?

Comment: @user3783243 The positioning doesn't happen, it always positions at the top.

Comment: @BillPurvis Please add relevant code to the question.

Comment: No need, I have solved the problem. I had put the id='tag' inside the <tr> tag, but this seems to be ignored. Putting a separate <a id='tag'></a> and putting the '#tag' at the end of the URL works. Sorry if I have wasted anyone's time on this!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.